How to give this sum a bound?
Let $x,y\in\mathbb{Z},$ consider the sum below
$$\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\\ x\neq y}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{4}}\Bigg|\frac{1}{|x|^{4}}-\frac{1}{|y|^{4}}\Bigg|,$$
is there anything I could do to give this sum a bound? For example, it this sum finite, or might it actually be $0?$

The only attempt I could think of is
$$\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{4}}\Bigg|\frac{1}{|x|^{4}}-\frac{1}{|y|^{4}}\Bigg|=2\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\\|x|< |y|}\frac{1}{|x-y|^4}\bigg(\frac{1}{|x|^{4}}-\frac{1}{|y|^{4}}\bigg),$$
but then I don't know how to proceed.

Than you very much for any of your helps!

I would first try $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x-(x+k)|^{4}}\Bigg|\frac{1}{|x|^{4}}-\frac{1}{|(x+k)|^{4}}\Bigg|$.

This is a sum of positive terms, so definitely not $0$.

Why there are absolute values around $x$, $y$ and $x-y$ if they're raised to the fourth power?

@GregMartin I don't know if I would say that the sum have positive terms when some of them are undefined.

@jjagmath Good point, presumably the OP needs to add $x\ne 0$ and $y\ne 0$ to the conditions of summation.

too symmetrical, should be $0$ imo

Expanding on the idea from my comment and the attempt by the OP, I will establish $8\times 15 \times \left(\frac{\pi^4}{90}\right)^2$ is an upper bound for the sum, assuming $x,y\neq0$ in the sum.
Either $x,y$ have the same sign (two cases) or different signs (two cases) so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}\\ x\neq y}\frac{1}{(x-y)^{4}}\Bigg|\frac{1}{x^{4}}-\frac{1}{y^{4}}\Bigg| &= 
2\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{N}\\ x\neq y} \frac{1}{(x-y)^{4}}\Bigg|\frac{1}{x^{4}}-\frac{1}{y^{4}}\Bigg| 
+ 2\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{(x+y)^{4}}\Bigg|\frac{1}{x^{4}}-\frac{1}{y^{4}}\Bigg| \\
&= 4 \sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{N}\\ x < y} \frac{1}{(x-y)^{4}}\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}-\frac{1}{y^{4}}\right) 
+ 4\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{N} \\ x < y} \frac{1}{(x+y)^{4}}\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}-\frac{1}{y^{4}}\right) \\
&= 4\sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}\frac{(x+k)^4-x^4}{x^4(x+k)^4} 
+ 4 \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2x+k)^4}\frac{(x+k)^4-x^4}{x^4(x+k)^4}
\end{align*}
Where $y=x+k$. Let $S := \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}\frac{(x+k)^4-x^4}{x^4(x+k)^4}$ and $T := \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2x+k)^4}\frac{(x+k)^4-x^4}{x^4(x+k)^4} $. Then I need an upper bound for $4S+4T.$ Since $k<2x+k$ we have $T<S,$ so the sum in question is bounded above by $8S.$ Hence I need to find an upper bound for $S$.
Notice $(x+k)^4 = x^4 + 4x^3 k +6 x^2 k^2 + 4x k^3 + k^4$, so
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}\frac{4x^3 k +6 x^2 k^2 + 4x k^3 + k^4}{x^4(x+k)^4} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{xk^3(x+k)^4}
+ \frac{6}{x^2k^2(x+k)^4} + \frac{4}{x^3k(x+k)^4} + \frac{1}{x^4(x+k)^4} \\
&< \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{x^4k^4}
+ \frac{6}{x^4k^4} + \frac{4}{x^4k^4} + \frac{1}{x^4k^4}
\end{align*}
Where for the first term I used $(x+k)^4=(x+k)^3(x+k)>(x+0)^3(0+k)$ and similar estimates for the other three terms. Hence,
$$
S< \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{15}{x^4k^4}=15  \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}\right)^2 = 15 \left(\frac{\pi^4}{90}\right)^2
$$
The last equal used Evaluate $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^4} $using Parseval's theorem (Fourier series)
Consequently, the sum in the question is bounded above by $8\times 15 \times \left(\frac{\pi^4}{90}\right)^2$.

Thanks for your detailed solution, this is very helpful!
